# Flutter web : Textfield with editor

Tags: flutter, web, flutter-web

I search since 5 hours for a textfield with an editor like this : [image: this] :

So multiline and with editor.

EDIT :

My temporary solution :

[image: solution]

```
final _commentMarkdownTextContributorCreateMissionView = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 24.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Tout comprendre sur le "),
          InkWell(
            child: Text(
              "Markdown",
              style: TextStyle(color: IneatColors.pink),
            ),
            onTap: () async {
              if (await canLaunch("https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown")) {
                await launch("https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown");
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

final _contextMissionMarkdownTextInputContributorCreateMissionView =
        Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 24.0, bottom: 12.0),
      child: MarkdownTextInput(
        (String value) => model.setOnTextChangedContext(value),
        model.contextMarkdownTextInput,
        label: 'Contexte',
      ),
    );

    final _contextMissionMarkdownBodyContributorCreateMissionView = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 24.0, left: 12.0),
      child: MarkdownBody(
        data: model.contextMarkdownTextInput,
      ),
    );
```

flutter_markdown:
  # #Markdown : https://pub:dev/packages/flutter_markdown:

markdown_editable_textinput:
  # Text input : https://pub:dev/packages/markdown_editable_textinput#-example-tab-:

Markdown language in the textfield works but the not the tools for the moment, so if you have a solution.

Can you healp me ? Compatible for flutter web

Comment: help please ! It's important for me !

Comment: Have you tried this package called zefyr..!  https://pub.dev/packages/zefyr. Its still early preview but might help and you can fork and add required features as you wish. Also follow this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12675)

Comment: @MayuriXx hey, diid you find a solution for this. I too need a similar text editor in flutter-web. I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: @SivaPerumal i edited my post and i give a solution

Comment: very nice, easy to use editor.  refreshing.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this plugin would help you.
I have copied the example code of plugin here.
[flutter_markdown][1]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_markdown/flutter_markdown.dart';

const String _markdownData = """
# Markdown Example
Markdown allows you to easily include formatted text, images, and even formatted Dart code in your app.

## Titles

Setext-style
```

## This is an H1

### This is an H2

```
Atx-style
```

## This is an H1

### This is an H2

This is an H6

```
Select the valid headers:

- [x] `# hello`
- [ ] `#hello`

## Links

[Google's Homepage][Google]
```

[inline-style](https://www.google.com)

[reference-style][Google]

```
## Images

![Flutter logo](/dart-lang/site-shared/master/src/_assets/image/flutter/icon/64.png)

## Tables

|Syntax                                 |Result                               |
|---------------------------------------|-------------------------------------|
|`*italic 1*`                           |*italic 1*                           |
|`_italic 2_`                           | _italic 2_                          |
|`**bold 1**`                           |**bold 1**                           |
|`__bold 2__`                           |__bold 2__                           |
|`This is a ~~strikethrough~~`          |This is a ~~strikethrough~~          |
|`***italic bold 1***`                  |***italic bold 1***                  |
|`___italic bold 2___`                  |___italic bold 2___                  |
|`***~~italic bold strikethrough 1~~***`|***~~italic bold strikethrough 1~~***|
|`~~***italic bold strikethrough 2***~~`|~~***italic bold strikethrough 2***~~|

## Styling
Style text as _italic_, __bold__, ~~strikethrough~~, or `inline code`.

- Use bulleted lists
- To better clarify
- Your points

## Code blocks
Formatted Dart code looks really pretty too:
```

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: Markdown(data: markdownData),
    ),
  ));
}

```
## Markdown widget

This is an example of how to create your own Markdown widget:

    Markdown(data: 'Hello _world_!');

Enjoy!

[Google]: https://www.google.com/
""";

void main() {
  final controller = ScrollController();

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: "Markdown Demo",
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Markdown Demo'),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Markdown(
            controller: controller,
            selectable: true,
            data: _markdownData,
            imageDirectory: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com',
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
          onPressed: () => controller.animateTo(0,
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.easeOut),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}


  [1]: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I do not know. When I just try Markdown, it doesn't work. By cons MarkdownBody works well but I do not see how it could work in a TextField?

Comment: You can make a normal text field and show the context down in a container just like stack overflow. See there's a container showing everything you right in the text field.

Comment: I will try it this week :)

Comment: I did with markdownTextInput and MarkdownBody for print result